# Convert a string to BarSubItem Devexpress

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I want to convert a string to BarSubItem Devexpress

```
Dim BarParmTxt As String

BarParmTxt = "BarFile"

Dim subMenu = TryCast(BarParmTxt, BarSubItem)
subMenu.Enabled = False
```

**
I have this issue Value of type string cannot be converted to barSubItem**

I want to use this to user permissions I have a table contain all form name and BarSubItem name and every user has each user has a specific set of permissions
so i want to pass BarSubItem name ans use
subMenu.Enabled = False
and use subMenu.Enabled = True  If the user has permission

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraBars.BarSubItem <- this fairly clearly shows how to add the menu items.

Comment: Maybe you need to expand your question a little on exactly what you're attempting to do.  A string is not something that can be cast to a complex type such as UI control

Comment: I want to use this to user permissions I have a table contain all form name and BarSubItem name and every user has each user has a specific set of permissions
so i want to pass BarSubItem name ans use
 subMenu.Enabled = False
and use subMenu.Enabled = True  If the user has permission